# How to Generate Swagger UI from documentation comments?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

in SpringBoot I always generate my Swagger UI directly out of the JavaDoc Annotations that I use in my controller. This is very helpful cause I don't need any Swagger Definition Files.

Is there a way to do the same in MongoDB/express/mongoose?

Actually, I implemented `apiDoc.js` that works fine. Just add some `@Annotations` and generate the UI.

But I wanna do same for swagger.

Here is my example of how I did it with `apiDocs.js`. I need something similar for Swagger.

```js
/**
 * @apiVersion 0.1.0
 * @api {get} /checklist/ Request All Checklists
 * @apiSampleRequest http://localhost:3005/checklist
 * @apiName Find Checklist
 * @apiGroup Checklist
 * @apiDescription Returns all CheckList with all CheckItems
 * @apiExample {curl} Example usage:
 *     curl -i http://localhost:3005/checklist
 */
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    CheckList.find()
        .then(CheckList => res.json(CheckList))
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
});
```

Any Liks to tutorials or examples will be helpful.